# Python "if" condition difference between "and" & "or"

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I want the user to decide whether or not a selected file gets deleted by saying exactly "yes" or "no". For what ever reason "yes" works however "no" loops back round and decides to go back to initial if statement

I have tried a few things, after some google searches I cannot seem to find a response that is suited to this issues. I have tried:

Changing the inputText with str() and without str()

I have tried Quotes and apostrophes on string texts.

I have tried changing the initial If Statement:

First:

```py
if inputText != ('yes' or 'no'):
```

and I have even tried

Second:

```py
if inputText != 'yes' or inputText != 'no':
```

Third:

```py
if (inputText != 'yes') or (inputText != 'no'):
```

The closest I've got is First. For some reason 'yes' seems to work but 'no' seems to loop back to the first If Statement.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? What am I missing?

```py
inputText = str(input("Are you sure you want to delete file? (yes/no) "))
ctrl = True
while ctrl == True:
    if inputText != ('yes' or 'no'):
        inputText = input('Please type "yes" or "no" ')
    elif inputText == 'yes':
        ##delete
        print("pretend got deleted")
        ctrl = False
    elif inputText == 'no':
        ##shit does not get deleted
        print("pretend doesn't got deleted")
        ctrl = False
```

The Results I anticipated would be a simple

```py
>> Are you sure you want to delete file? (yes/no) *random text that isn't 'yes' or 'no'*
>> Please type "yes" or "no"
```

This is what I get with First of my initial If Statement example:

```py
>> Are you sure you want to delete file? (yes/no) yes
>> pretend got deleted
```

This is what I anticipate:

```py
>> Are you sure you want to delete file (yes/no) no
>> pretend doesn't got deleted
```

This is what I actually get

```py
>> Are you sure you want to delete file (yes/no) no
>> Please type "yes" or "no"
```

even if I do:

```py
>> Are you sure you want to delete file (yes/no) no
>> Please type "yes" or "no" yes
>> pretend got deleted
```

is the result I get

Comment: you can use `if (inputText != 'yes') and (inputText != 'no'):`

Comment: @Lyncius. Check out my answer and let me know if you don't follow

Answer (score 2):

The issue lies with in your first if statement. Your first if, `if inputText != ('yes' or 'no')` resolves to true as soon as it sees that your input is not `yes`. So change your if to resolve to `true` only when input is not `yes` and not `no` which resolves to `if inputText != ('yes') and inputText != ('no')`

Your code would look as below

```py
inputText = str(input("Are you sure you want to delete file? (yes/no) "))
ctrl = True
while ctrl == True:
    if inputText != ('yes') and inputText != ('no'):
        inputText = input('Please type "yes" or "no" ')
    elif inputText == 'yes':
        ##delete
        print("pretend got deleted")
        ctrl = False
    elif inputText == 'no':
        ##shit does not get deleted
        print("pretend doesn't got deleted")
        ctrl = False
```

Comment: I tried this out and the result is the opposite to what I had, the "no" If statement goes through but the "yes" If statement no longer works and it goes straight back to the initial if statement

Comment: @Lyncius my bad. I constructed the if wrong which caused the issue. I had updated my answer. Give it a try now

Comment: Like a charm! Okay cool. To be fair if I looked over your first paragraph again, I would of noticed the same line of code. I'm still trying to grasp why `if inputText != ('yes' or 'no')` did not work.

Comment: Take this case where you have entered `no`,  so the control comes to this if block and as this expression is an `or` condition , if part of the statement is true then it considered true. So it comes to the block and makes the comparison if it is not `yes` and as you entered `no`, it will take it as yea it is not `yes` and prints it out

Comment: Do not forget to accept and upvote the answer if you feel like it's solved the issue for you :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is with your logic, in particular this line:

```
inputText != ('yes' or 'no')
```

The ('yes' or 'no') resolves to 'yes', since that's the first element there that evaluates to True (in a boolean context) - to put it another way, that line is functionally equivalent to the block of code below:

```
if bool('yes') is True:
    compare_value='yes'
else:
    compare_value='no'
if inputText != compare_value:
    inputText = input('Please type "yes" or "no" ')
```

You probably meant to do this:

```
inputText = str(input("Are you sure you want to delete file? (yes/no) "))
ctrl = True
while ctrl == True:
    if inputText not in ('yes', 'no',):
        inputText = input('Please type "yes" or "no" ')
    elif inputText == 'yes':
        ##delete
        print("pretend got deleted")
        ctrl = False
    elif inputText == 'no':
        ##shit does not get deleted
        print("pretend doesn't got deleted")
        ctrl = False
```

A few notes here:

1. Now you are testing whether the inputText is not in the set of values that contains 'yes' and 'no' ( inputText not in ('yes','no',) )
2. Note the trailing comma in that set ('yes','no',)  (just before the closing parenthesis) - in Python the () is used for order of operations as well as to define a set - so if you stick a value in parens ('yes') => That's the same as 'yes' .  The trailing comma ('yes',) will make Python realize that you meant to define a set - and consider it as such.  Now, strictly speaking, if there is more than a single value a comma isn't needed at the end i.e., ('yes','no') would be okay - but it's a "best practice" to get in the habit of always sticking that trailing comma in, so you don't end up accidentally trying to define a single element set at some point and end up with just a value.

Comment: I understand the concept behind ("yes","no"). If I'm right it's like declaring a check against these in the order given? (correct me if I'm wrong). But the trailing comma? that is rather... confusing.

Comment: @lyncius - try doing this - print(('yes' or no')) - it will always print yes because the "or" expression translates in python to "return the first value that evaluates to True in a boolean context"

Also, once you look over the answers, be sure to upvote/accept the answer that'll be the most helpful to stackoverflow users asking the same/similar questions.

Comment: @Lyncius - the ("yes", "no",) is a "set" of values.  The expression "inputText not in ("yes","no",)" means "check to see if the inputText is not one of the values in the set of (permissable) values" - if it is not in the set, then evaluate to true; otherwise evalulate to False.